# Bootstrap columns plus or minus gutterwidth

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I use Twitter Bootstrap with lesscss. I like the gridsystem but how could I define a class to add or subtract the gutterwidth from a `.spanX` class like `.span3` or `.span11`?
Something like this:

```
.addgutter {
    width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1)) + @gridGutterWidth; 
}
.subtractgutter{
    width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1)) - @gridGutterWidth; 
}
```

But this is the whole sitewidth add/subtraced the gutterwidth. I need it so that automatically the columnwidth is set plus or minus the gutterwidth.
Actually I'm not really familiar with less, I've been using it for under three months.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the Twitter Bootstrap's CSS according to your requirement through the link given below. I hope this helps.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: Hi, sorry no that doesn´t helps because my problem is not that I don´t know how I can change the grid. I need a new operation for the grid which is not exist in Bootstrap. And I don´t know which variable is vor the actual used columns count in the corresponding used span-class.